# MS SQL Server 2019 OpenRowSet Bulk Insert with CSV file - (0 rows affected)

Tags: sql-server, insert, ssms, bulk, openrowset

I am attempting to load a CSV file onto MS SQL Server with OPENROWSET BULK INSERT and 0 rows are being inserted.

I am using the following code within SQL Server Management Studio;

```sql
-- DROP TABLE finances.dbo.MasterCard_Import_CSV;

CREATE TABLE finances.dbo.MasterCard_Import_CSV (
    Date datetime
    , Type varchar(10)
    , Description varchar(100)
    , Value float
    , Balance float
    , Name varchar(20)
    , Account varchar(50));

INSERT INTO finances.dbo.MasterCard_Import_CSV
    SELECT * FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'C:\dev\workspace\Portfolio\DataAnalyst_2_Finances\RawData\BJKEOGH-MASTERCARD.csv'
        , FORMATFILE = 'C:\dev\workspace\Portfolio\DataAnalyst_2_Finances\OpenRowSet_BulkImport_Scripts\MASTERCARD_csv_file_import_set.txt'
        , FIRSTROW=2
        , FORMAT='CSV'
    ) AS TMP
```

The contents of the format file are as follows (i have added a blank line to the bottom of the file);

```
15.0
7
1 SQLCHAR 0 10 ',' 1 Date SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
2 SQLCHAR 0 10 ',' 2 Type SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
3 SQLCHAR 0 100 ',' 3 Description SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
4 SQLCHAR 0 10 ',' 4 Value SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
5 SQLCHAR 0 10 ',' 5 Balance SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
6 SQLCHAR 0 20 ',' 6 Name SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
7 SQLCHAR 0 50 '\r\n' 7 Account SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

A sample of the CSV file is as follows;

```
Date, Type, Description, Value, Balance, Account Name, Account
09-Nov-21,Purchase,'AMZNMKTPLACE AMAZON.CO AMAZON.CO.UK GBR,17.99,,'B J KEOGH,'121212******1212
09-Nov-21,Purchase,'MARKS AND SPENCER PLC BIRMINGHAM GBR,10.85,,'B J KEOGH,'121212******1212
10-Nov-21,Purchase,'DVA LICENSING COLERAINE GBR,30,,'B J KEOGH,'121212******1212
10-Nov-21,Purchase,'TESCO STORES 5392 BIRMINGHAM GBR,1.3,,'B J KEOGH,'121212******1212
11-Nov-21,Purchase,'TESCO STORES 6227 HOCKLEY GBR,13.9,,'B J KEOGH,'121212******1212
12-Nov-21,Purchase,'Prime Video*QR1EA1PT5 353-12477661 GBR,7.99,,'B J KEOGH,'121212******1212
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Presumably the SQL Server Service account has access to the file?

Comment: Second one today - 20 years after Y2k and we repeat the mistakes.

Comment: On a separate note, `float` is a **terrible** choice of data type for what are very likely monetary values.

Comment: And your CSV formatting is off. Your description column lacks a closing single quote. But that alone will not solve your problem as you have strings that contain commas.

Comment: What is the actual line separator, is it actually `\r\n`? Open with a hex editor or Notepad++ to check

Comment: Yes, SQL Server Service has access to the file directory.

Comment: @SMor The CSV format only specifies `"` as a quoting mechanism. A single quote `'` does not need escaping. Excel inserts single-quotes when you format the column as Text

Comment: If that is the case, then those `'` should not be in the OP's CSV file, @Charlieface . When you save an excel file as a CSV file, it doesn't include those leading single quotes.

Comment: @Larnu You're right, I'm misremembering. You need to *add* an apostrophe to force it to view as text, Presumably OP has done that because of this issue. Either way, it does not need escaping and should not make `OPENROWSET` fail

Comment: I think the format file is supposed to have separators in double-quotes, so `","` and `"\r\n"`

Comment: This is the same CSV file opened in Notepad++Date, Type, Description, Value,

Comment: The same CSV file opened in Notepad++ shows CRLF at the end of each line

Comment: I tried the "" double quotes and it returned an error with regards to the format of the format file, i changed these to single quotes and there was no error but no data was loaded

Comment: I made a new copy of the CSV and the format file which excluded the NAME and ACCOUNT columns and data and still (0 rows affected) returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your format file. Remove the single quotes, and the `INSERT` works fine:

```
15.0
7
1 SQLCHAR 0 0 , 1 Date SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
2 SQLCHAR 0 0 , 2 Type SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
3 SQLCHAR 0 0 , 3 Description SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
4 SQLCHAR 0 0 , 4 Value SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
5 SQLCHAR 0 0 , 5 Balance SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
6 SQLCHAR 0 0 , 6 Name SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
7 SQLCHAR 0 0 \r\n 7 Account SQL_LATIN1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

Once I did that, your data was opened without issue.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the file was read correctly.]

Comment: Larnu, thank you so much, how did you manage to know that?  I had been scouring the web for two days trying to get this working?